# Wired network is connected & acquires IP address but the internet is not working

Tags: networking, internet, dhcp, wired

So the other day when my network died completely without a warning at first. I thought it may have been the modem or the router (the modem can't handle to many connections as its a a bit dodgy); but neither was the problem.

I had to re-install Linux system due to a messed up graphics driver (it was my fault which I did something totally wrong and couldn't get it to work again). But my wired connection will not connect to the internet. I do have an IP Address, Submask, IPV6 address and the light on the Ethernet port at the back is transmitting data with green & orange LED's, also my WiFi connection still works perfectly.

I've posted my inxi output, syslog & ifconfig. If there is any one that can advise me a with this, that would be awesome.

INXI -Fxn output Below:

```
System: Host: hydr4 Kernel: 3.8.0-35-generic i686 (32 bit, gcc: 4.7.3) 
       Desktop: Xfce 4.10.2 (Gtk 2.24.16) Distro: Linux Mint 15 Olivia
Machine:   System: Compaq-Presario product: RR501AA-ABU SR2129UK
       Mobo: ASUSTek model: LEONITE version: 5.00 Bios: Phoenix version: 5.10 date: 01/30/2007
CPU: Dual core Intel Core2 CPU 6300 (-MCP-) cache: 2048 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 7469.08 
       Clock Speeds: 1: 1600.00 MHz 2: 1867.00 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GF119 [GeForce GT 610] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
       X.Org: 1.13.3 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau) Resolution: 1024x768@60.0hz, 1024x768@60.0hz 
       GLX Renderer: GeForce GT 610/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 310.44 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio: Card-1: Intel NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
       Card-2: NVIDIA GF119 HDMI Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k3.8.0-35-generic
Network: Card-1: Intel NM10/ICH7 Family LAN Controller driver: e100 ver: 3.5.24-k2-NAPI port: ef00 bus-ID: 02:08.0
       IF: eth0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 00:1a:92:69:c7:f1
       Card-2: Realtek RTL8187 Wireless Adapter driver: rtl8187 usb-ID: 0bda:8187
       IF: wlan0 state: down mac: 00:c0:ca:75:44:a7
```

IFCONFIG OUTPUT:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:92:69:c7:f1  
      inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21a:92ff:fe69:c7f1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:419 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:33431 (33.4 KB)  TX bytes:44861 (44.8 KB)
```

SYSLOG:

```
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) starting connection 'Wired connection 1'
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> (eth0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> (eth0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> (eth0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> dhclient started with pid 4698
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 avahi-daemon[1221]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::21a:92ff:fe69:c7f1 on eth0.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 avahi-daemon[1221]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::21a:92ff:fe69:c7f1.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 avahi-daemon[1221]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: All rights reserved.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: 
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/00:1a:92:69:c7:f1
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/00:1a:92:69:c7:f1
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.100 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x760a69a9)
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.100 from 192.168.1.1
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 dhclient: bound to 192.168.1.100 -- renewal in 3099 seconds.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> (eth0): DHCPv4 state changed preinit -> reboot
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info>   address 192.168.1.100
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info>   gateway 192.168.1.1
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 avahi-daemon[1221]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.100.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 avahi-daemon[1221]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 avahi-daemon[1221]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.100 on eth0.IPv4.
Feb  8 12:14:19 hydr4 kernel: [  970.652409] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:f3:c1:5b:80:c4:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Feb  8 12:14:20 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> (eth0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Feb  8 12:14:20 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Feb  8 12:14:20 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> (eth0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Feb  8 12:14:20 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Feb  8 12:14:20 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Feb  8 12:14:20 hydr4 dnsmasq[1472]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Feb  8 12:14:20 hydr4 dnsmasq[1472]: using nameserver 192.168.1.1#53
Feb  8 12:14:20 hydr4 avahi-daemon[1221]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::21a:92ff:fe69:c7f1.
Feb  8 12:14:20 hydr4 avahi-daemon[1221]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Feb  8 12:14:20 hydr4 avahi-daemon[1221]: Registering new address record for fe80::21a:92ff:fe69:c7f1 on eth0.*.
Feb  8 12:14:25 hydr4 kernel: [  977.312309] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:a0:f3:c1:5b:80:c4:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2 
Feb  8 12:14:34 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) successful, device activated.
Feb  8 12:14:34 hydr4 dbus[1143]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' (using servicehelper)
Feb  8 12:14:34 hydr4 dbus[1143]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Feb  8 12:14:37 hydr4 nm-dispatcher.action: Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown' took too long; killing it.
Feb  8 12:14:37 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <warn> Dispatcher script timed out: Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/01ifupdown' timed out.
Feb  8 12:14:39 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Feb  8 12:14:39 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Feb  8 12:14:39 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Feb  8 12:14:39 hydr4 NetworkManager[1233]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
```

IFCONFIG WLAN0 CONNECTED:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:92:69:c7:f1  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21a:92ff:fe69:c7f1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:165 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26568 (26.5 KB)  TX bytes:40779 (40.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:22856 (22.8 KB)  TX bytes:22856 (22.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:ca:75:44:a7  
          inet addr:192.168.1.104  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2c0:caff:fe75:44a7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1806 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1959 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1369477 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:376277 (376.2 KB)
```

IFCONFIG ETH0 CONNECTED:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:92:69:c7:f1  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21a:92ff:fe69:c7f1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:171 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:326 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:27505 (27.5 KB)  TX bytes:49977 (49.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:277 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:23173 (23.1 KB)  TX bytes:23173 (23.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:ca:75:44:a7  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2c0:caff:fe75:44a7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1908 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2066 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1392844 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:463109 (463.1 KB)
```

Comment: As in your question, you mentioned that WiFi works. Does that mean you're able to browse internet too?? Also, could you please try restarting your network manager first with `sudo service network-manager restart` & let us know whether that helps! :)

Comment: Yes I can browse the internet on WiFi but not on my ethernet connection this is what is confusing me if I run sudo service network-manager restart, I have to reboot the machnine as the network manager doesn't come back up, I'm starting to think this may be a problem with my ethernet port rather than linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can **statically** set your IP address by doing this -

- Go to folder */etc/network/*
- You can see a file called *interfaces*
- Just make a backup copy of it somewhere safe and open in gedit
- Originally the file may contain following

  ```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback
  ```
- Now add the following things to the file

  ```
  auto lo
      iface lo inet loopback
  auto eth0
      iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.1.108
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      network 192.168.1.0
      broadcast 192.168.1.255
      gateway 192.168.1.1
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222
  ```
- Enter all your required details and save the file (all above details are examples)
- Now restart your networking service by typing following command in terminal

  ```
  sudo service networking restart
  ```
- **Note** : For wifi you just replace **eth0** by **wlan0**

Comment: After trying the above all I get is an unmanaged device and I've tried editing it via the network-manager by adding a new wired static connection but I get an error "(32) Connection Could Not Be Found" if it's a static connection.

Comment: I would not recommend adding static IP's as the questioner is able to acquire IP address at initially. Revert back your interfaces settings to its default & try my comment. Also please post the complete output of `ifconfig -a` :)

Comment: I've added two sections with the ifconfig -a output thats wlan0 connected and eth0 connected, this is the problem it connects perfectly and I can browse to the router's address 192.168.1.1 I can also log in to the router via the wired connection but there's no internet which is what's confusing the hell out of me ... everything over DHCP works on WiFI

Comment: Here's my teamviewer id & pass as I am completely stumped with this the internet works just not with a wired connection ... 

ID: 837 279 085
Pass: 7729

Comment: it looks like you do not have a default route configured. Wht is the output of route -n when connected via ethernet